# What is the best Docker tagging strategy?

Tags: jenkins, docker, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment

It is certain, that "latest" tag is not enough (i.e. if you want to rollback/debug).

What is the best docker tagging practice? Is it better to tag it with build number or commit number? Or some other option?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We don't use tagging for development environment, because we have pretty nice test coverage, but I suggest, you can easily tag container with your CI tool build number (Teamcity, Jenkins), something like

> docker build -t **{yourserviceName}:{JENKINS BUILD NUMBER}**

However, production deployments - is a little bit different story.
We use two tags for that - **previous** and **latest**

1.Build production container on teh build server

2.Push it to shared repo

3.Pull to production server.

The **latest** tag is always contained at shared repository.
Before step 3, just re-tag existing running container to
**previous**.

What's the benefit?

If you have your **latest** container with critical failure, you just rollback to **previous** one. It's extremely rare case, when you have to do a rapid rollback, let's say, *4 deployments back*, so no need to maintain versions there

Answer (score 0):

I would say go with an older one cause they might look more stable. But you can refer to this:
https://hub.docker.com/_/node/tags

To get an idea of which one is suitable for you.